In Red Hat Developer Studio (similar to Eclipse), can't create bookmark inside a .xhtml file
Inside Red Hat Developer Studio (similar to Eclipse), if I open a .xhtml file, I can't create a bookmark. But I can create bookmark for .java file.
What I tried - I looked into Window -> Preferences and looked for anything related to bookmarks but didn't find anything.
There is a section in 'Preferences' related to Java editor and HTML editor but nothing in there stands out as far as enabling bookmarks is concerned.

It is up to the individual editors to implement support for Bookmarks. Editors extending the standard text editor will inherit support, but others may not have it at all.
